# Равномерно растянуть `not-NaN` значения столбца DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Не могу решить. У нас есть:

df1 ( у него вторая колонка заполнена в верхней части числами и иногда буквами)
[image: df1]

надо получить таблицу в таком виде, то есть мы как бы растягиваем числа по всей колонке как "гармошку" по всей длине, образовав примерно равные расстояния между числами. Можно "гармошку" не дотягивать до самого конца, так как не получится, но сделать шаг максимальным чтобы все значения влезли.

df2
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там где пустые места - у вас там пустая строка или NaN?

Comment: там стоит NaN да,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.arange(1, 21)})
df.loc[:6, 'val'] = [11,10,9,8,7,6,5]
```

---

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]:
    ID   val
0    1  11.0
1    2  10.0
2    3   9.0
3    4   8.0
4    5   7.0
5    6   6.0
6    7   5.0
7    8   NaN
8    9   NaN
9   10   NaN
10  11   NaN
11  12   NaN
12  13   NaN
13  14   NaN
14  15   NaN
15  16   NaN
16  17   NaN
17  18   NaN
18  19   NaN
19  20   NaN
```

решение:

```
def stretch(s, step):
    # create a series of NaN's
    ret = pd.Series([np.nan] * len(s), s.index)
    # extract not-NaN values
    vals = s.loc[:s.isnull().idxmax()-1].values
    # stretch not-NaN values over the series
    ret.iloc[::step] = vals
    return ret

df['val'] = stretch(df['val'])
```

результат:

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]:
    ID   val
0    1  11.0
1    2   NaN
2    3   NaN
3    4  10.0
4    5   NaN
5    6   NaN
6    7   9.0
7    8   NaN
8    9   NaN
9   10   8.0
10  11   NaN
11  12   NaN
12  13   7.0
13  14   NaN
14  15   NaN
15  16   6.0
16  17   NaN
17  18   NaN
18  19   5.0
19  20   NaN
```

Comment: Максим, вы сделали очень полезное дело для моей работы. Спасибо огромное!